# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation error occuring in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to follow a tutorial on JSP and eve after writing the same code in the tutorial i still receive following error.

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilationproblem: Duplicate local
>   variable cart.

I am trying to run the servlet with the following code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Cart cart = (Cart)session.getAttribute("cart");

        if (cart == null) {
            cart = new Cart();  
        }

        cart.setTotalItems(7);

        session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/showcart.jsp").forward(request,response);

    }


HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Duplicate local variable cart

demo.Session.doGet(Session.java:32)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 logs.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

showcart.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import= "demo.*" %>

<% Cart cart= (Cart)session.getAttribute("cart");%>

Items in cart : <%= cart.getTotalItems() %>
</body>
</html>
```

the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Session</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Session</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>demo.Session</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Session</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Session</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

session.java

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Session
 */
public class Session extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Session() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Cart cart = (Cart)session.getAttribute("cart");

        if (cart == null) {
            cart = new Cart();  
        }

        cart.setTotalItems(7);

        session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/showcart.jsp").forward(request,response);

    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: At wich line you got the error?

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace? And which servlet container are you using? Tomcat? What version?

Comment: @AlvinThompson using Tomcat 7.0

Comment: Please also say what class the `doGet` method above is in, and add the relevant sections of the `web.xml` file (`servlet` and `servlet-mapping`). Thanks.

Comment: So the class is `Session`, I presume. Let me think on it...

Comment: @AlvinThompson...the doGet method is in the Controller class (servlet). I posted the web.xml  above too, thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...is the Controller class small enough that you can post the whole thing?

Comment: And what's the (relative) URL you're hitting when you get the problem? The web root?

Comment: @AlvinThompson.You mean the web.xml ?

Comment: @AlvinThompson..somehow its working now, unfortunately, I don't know what went wrong ! Seems I have issues with the Tomcat, its not the first time. All the same, very grateful :)

Comment: Strange. The Eclipse compiler in Tomcat 7 is a bit flaky; I should have mentioned just undeploying and redeploying the app which often fixes these things. Just the same, I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting the error at runtime and not compile time, I don't think the issue has to do directly (if at all) with the code you've shown. That code was compiled when packaging the WAR file and not while the WAR file was deployed, and I assume it compiled fine if you got a WAR.

I'm guessing this duplicate variable is defined in the JSP file, which happens to also have a variable named "cart". JSP files are compiled "on the fly" at runtime, normally upon the first request. If you look in `showcart.jsp` you should see the true cause. The stack trace seems to support this, and you can verify what I say by renaming `cart` in the `doGet` method to something else--the error will still say "cart". If you don't see the cause in `showcart.jsp`, can you post its contents please?

Comment: +1 - Also look at the generated "showCart.java" file to see what the Java compiler is actually complaining about.

Comment: @StephenC?! Wow, I watch your show all the time! Good luck with The Late Show. :)

Comment: @StephenC: If you're not from the US, there's a famous person named Stephen Colbert.

Comment: Alvin - it might surprise you to know that people from outside the US know a lot about US culture.

Comment: @StephenC: Heh yup. I keep forgetting we're still the center of the universe until China takes over.

Comment: s/we're/think we are/p  :-)

Comment: @AlvinThompson sorry, i can't identify the error so i have displayed showcart.jsp. thanks !

Comment: @SyCode: I'm guessing the JSP is being embedded multiple times, but to verify this I'll need the info I asked for in the comment above.