# how can you find your pc host name?

Tags: host

i want to put the right URL ,to connect it to the data base:

`String CONNECTION_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/fun";`

so i am not able to execute my program pls help me out for the right URL, i.e how to find my host name, and can u give me any tips to connect to DB.

Comment: Use `127.0.0.1` no rocket science. Even though localhost should work fine already

Comment: What are you talking about??? We don't even know what you are doing!

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  i am getting this erroe after executing

Comment: it shoud b in this format it seems:"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/fun"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation error occuring in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224703/java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-error-occuring-in-jsp)

Comment: `localhost` is your computer's hostname, at least from the perspective of your computer.  As for what you might be doing wrong, we can't know given the information presented here.

Comment: i am trying to connect to the database

Comment: i just want to know my pc localhost name  , any menthods to find it?

Comment: Wouldn't a compilation error point to a coding problem, not a connection string issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can type on your pc command prompt:  hostname

or in windows go to [image]

if ur using it on an online server try: localhost

Comment: ya i am using it online,its taking me to xampp if i type localhost online

Comment: just type localhost ...it need your hostname not the one from your pc but the server

Comment: CONNECTION_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost"  or CONNECTION_URL="localhost"  or CONNECTION_URL="mysql://localhost"

Comment: try those and see if it helps